# WPF Show buttons inside a selected ListItem

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, listbox, wpf-controls

I'm working with a WPF application to manage our main software's versions. This application has a `ListBox`, and I set the `ListBox.DataTemplate` to each `ListBoxItem` has a `Label` and 2 `Buttons` inside it.

The following code shows my `ListBox` code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedVersion}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PatchList, Mode=TwoWay}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel}}"
                 SelectionMode="Single" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectedIndex="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=VersionNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontSize="19" />

                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Width="25" Height="25" Template="{StaticResource OnMouseOverListBoxitem}" ToolTip="Release" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ReleaseVersionCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Release}" />
                        </Button>

                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="25" Height="25" Template="{StaticResource OnMouseOverListBoxitem}" ToolTip="Trash" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteVersionCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Trash}" />
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The problem is that I would like to show the label and the buttons **ONLY** for the `Selected ListBoxItem`.

By the way, I'm using `bindings`, and if you see some different code it's because I'm also using `MahApp.Metro` for Windows8-style.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to use relativesource binding for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one.

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter1" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fnts}" Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedVersion}" 
                 SelectionMode="Single" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectedIndex="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding}" />
                        <Button Content=" X " Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter1}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```